# react redux not changes component after store change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm stating to learn react and redux so i think there are many things that i don't know. 
I have a problem with missed re-rendering component on store changes.

This is my project structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJJSg.png

And here is my code:

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <Nav sortByDate={()=>{this.props.sortBy(SORT_BY_DATE)}} sortByLikes={()=>{this.props.sortBy(SORT_BY_LIKES)}} />
                <Items comments={this.props.comments} getList={()=>{this.props.sortBy(GET_LIST)}}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        comments: state.comments
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        sortBy: (action) => {
            dispatch(sortBy(action));
        }
    };
};

export default connect (mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (App);
```

CommentList.js:

```
class ListItems extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            comments: props.comments
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.getList();
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.comments !== nextProps.comments) {
            this.setState({
                comments: nextProps.comments
            });
        }
    }


    getComments() {
        return (this.state.comments.map(function (object) {
            return <Item numLikes={object.num_like} id={object.id} comment={object.comment} date={object.date}
                         sender={object.sender}/>
        }));
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col lg={2} md={1} xs={0}/>
                    <Col lg={8} md={10} xs={12}>
                        {this.getComments()}
                    </Col>
                    <Col lg={2} md={16} xs={0}/>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default ListItems;
```

Reducers.js:

```
const listReducer = (state = {comments: []}, action) => {

    function toDate(dateStr) {
        const [day, month, year] = dateStr.split("/")
        return new Date(year, month - 1, day)
    }

    function commentSortedByDate(comments) {

        const sorted = comments.sort(function(a, b) {
            return  toDate(b.date) - toDate(a.date);
        })

        return sorted;
    }

    function commentSortedByLikes(comments) {
        const sorted = comments.sort(function(a, b) {
            return  parseInt(b.num_like) - parseInt(a.num_like);
        })

        return sorted;
    }



    switch (action.type) {
        case SORT_BY_DATE:
            console.log("sort by date");

            state={
                comments: commentSortedByDate(state.comments)
            }
            break;

        case SORT_BY_LIKES:
            console.log("sort by likes");

            state={
                comments: commentSortedByLikes(state.comments)
            }
            break;

        case GET_LIST:
            state = {
                comments: action.payload
            }
            break;
    }
    return state;
};

export default listReducer;
```

The problem is certainly with this two components.
I have 3 actions:

- `GET_LIST` (in a middleware call a rest service getting the json of comments and update the store).
- `SORT_BY_DATE` (in the reducer sort the array of comments by date and update the store).
- `SORT_BY_LIKES` (same).
  The comments in the store are effectively sorted.

First of all the app dispatch automatically the `GET_LIST` action and it works, pass the props with comments correctly to the `CommentList.js` component and successfully render the list of `CommentItem`.

Now the problem:
The click of a button in the Navbar component will dispatch a `SORT_BY` action that updates the store and finally calls the `MapStateToProps` function in App, but this time the `CommentList` stay the same and `componentWillReceiveProps` is not called.

Why? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you share your reducer code?

Comment: Offtopic. Why do you put props to state? You know you could just use `this.props.comments` instead of `this.state...` inside `getComments` method.

Comment: (Reducer added) In truth i have always used this.props.comments but in the search for a solution i founded someone that uses this way. And if also this works with GET_LIST...

Comment: You could try `const sorted = Array.from(comments).sort(...`, as `sort` modifies the array in place.

Comment: no, it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating the state ([sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/sort)) instead of creating a new Array in your reducer. This prevents the component from re-rendering as it is not notified of a change. To fix it you could make your functions pure:

```
function commentSortedByDate(comments) {
    const copy = [...comments];
    copy.sort(function(a, b) {
        return  toDate(b.date) - toDate(a.date);
    })
    return copy;
}

function commentSortedByLikes(comments) {
    const copy = [...comments];
    copy.sort(function(a, b) {
        return  parseInt(b.num_like) - parseInt(a.num_like);
    })
    return copy;
}
```

This way you return **a new** array instead of old one (with sorted elements).

Comment: i'm sorry it still not work, but i think that you have hit the problem

Comment: @MattyxDrink-Drink- what if you do: `const mapStateToProps = state => ({ comments: [...state.comments] });` will this work?

Comment: i think we are close, now the componentWillReciveProps() is called and console.log-ing the props that will recive the component i can see that the comments are in the right order but the compoment still remain unchanged

Comment: Is setState called in componentWillReceiveProps ?

Comment: props changes, render method is called, so re-render, but the items remain in the same order... probably is the getComments() function?

Comment: was missing that one..Thank you!